# How to remove Highcharts grid end lines on x and y axis?

Tags: highcharts

I wish to remove the end line on Highcharts (as shown in image). Wish to show the Highcharts grid open.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the top grid line of yAxes is always the last item (highcharts-yaxis-grid > highcharts-grid-line) and the right grid line of xAxes is always before the last one (highcharts-xaxis-grid > highcharts-grid-line). You can find both grid lines and then set the `stroke-width` to 0px.

check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zypherscript/60e4asjv/5/

Comment: Using angular latest version. Not able to use same code in typescript.